# If I have a Google Map on my page, how do I draw a "circle" around it with a radius and a blue dot?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, google-maps

```
var newloc_options = {
                                zoom:15,
                                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                                mapTypeControl:false,
                                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                scrollwheel:false
                      };
var newloc_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("newloc_map_canvas"), newloc_options);
```

This is currently my code to draw a map.  How do I put a circle with a blue dot in the middle? (and a certain radius?)

I'm using V3 , and I have no clue where start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Circle)

```
// Add a Circle overlay to the map.
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              map: map,
              radius: 3000000 // 3000 km
            });
```